# How is the en_US locale supposed to work with printable characters

Tags: 14.04, locale

I have two ubuntu trusty system. One newly installed and one a little bit older.

On these systems, I have some troubles with the `en_US` locale, it behaves differently, most easily seen with this command:

```
printf '\xe5\xe4\xf6' | LANG=en_US LC_ALL=en_US hexdump -vC
```

On the older one I get the expected output:

```
00000000  e5 e4 f6                                          |åäö|
00000003
```

but on the newly installed one I get dots instead of åäö:

```
00000000  e5 e4 f6                                          |...|
00000003
```

I also checked on a CentOS 6 system and there I also get the output I expect (the first one). But, if I run `locale-gen --purge` on the older system, it changes to the newer (IMO incorrect) output.

Does anyone know if there's something I can do to make the new system generate the output I expect, or if there's something that's changed in this locale so that assented characters are no longer printable, or if there's anything else that could affect it?

localedef --list has identical output:

```
en_AG
en_AG.utf8
en_AU.utf8
en_BW.utf8
en_CA.utf8
en_DK.utf8
en_GB.utf8
en_HK.utf8
en_IE.utf8
en_IN
en_IN.utf8
en_NG
en_NG.utf8
en_NZ.utf8
en_PH.utf8
en_SG.utf8
en_US
en_US.iso88591
en_US.utf8
en_ZA.utf8
en_ZM
en_ZM.utf8
en_ZW.utf8
es_US
es_US.iso88591
es_US.utf8
```

Answer (score 2):

I found one way to print those characters using the en_US locale:

Press **Alt+F2** and run `env LANG=en_US gnome-terminal`. Then in the terminal window:

```
$ printf '\xe5\xe4\xf6\n'
åäö
$
```

This would indicate that there is no problem with the locale, at least, but it enables ISO-8859-1 encoding as expected.

*Edit:*

Printing using hexdump works fine too:

```
$ printf '\xe5\xe4\xf6' | hexdump -vC
00000000  e5 e4 f6                                          |åäö|
00000003
$
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't really help my issue, which is to get `hexdump` to print them. `printf` doesn't check if a character is considered printable before printing it, while hexdump does. I suppose the workaround is to use another tool, which I'm investigating now.

Comment: @PerJohansson: Just edited the answer to show that you can as well use hexdump to print the characters. The point is that the terminal emulator must have the right encoding.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get it back to working. First, remove all locales (I'm actually using a docker image so that part was just starting fresh), then

```
echo "en_US ISO-8859-1" >> /var/lib/locales/supported.d/local
dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

This generates working locale files. After this I can add the UTF-8 one without breaking it.

```
echo "en_US UTF-8" >> /var/lib/locales/supported.d/local
dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

Now I guess I have to go figure out how to do a bug report...